# How can I filter data in an Apex Grid to show certain things for certain user groups?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, security, oracle-apex

I have an ADMIN group and a USER group. My data looks something like this raw:

```
ID ---------- NAME --------- SECTOR
0001          John           A
0002          John           H
0024          John           A
0011          John           H
0045          John           A
```

The ADMIN group should only be able to see A, and the USER group should only be able to see H. 
How can I customize the gridview in Apex to filter it based on authorization/groups?

Comment: Are these built-in APEX groups or something of your own devising?

Comment: They are just groups in apex. Under Admin->Users & Groups. I use them for authorization schemes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using APEX built-in groups, there is a function [APEX_UTIL.GET_GROUPS_USER_BELONGS_TO](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E23903_01/doc/doc.41/e21676/apex_util.htm#BABGHFGB) that can help you here.  It returns a comma-separated list of the groups the user belongs to.  So you could use it something like this:

```
select id, name, sector
from employees
where ((','||apex_util.get_groups_user_belongs_to(:app_user)||',' like '%,ADMIN,%'
      and sector = 'A')
or (','||apex_util.get_groups_user_belongs_to(:app_user)||',' like '%,USER,%'
      and sector = 'H'))
```

Comment: Is there a way to execute apex_util.get_groups... manually for testing purposes?

Comment: From the SQL command window in Apex Builder you can run: `select apex_util.get_groups_user_belongs_to('JOHN') from dual`