# How can data in APEX grids be filtered based on user groups when a user is a member of multiple groups?

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I'm trying to filter data in an APEX report based on assignment to one or more user group. The user group name is used as a variable in the report allowing filtering of each row.

E.g. using the following data:

```
ID ---------- NAME --------- Group
0001          John           ADMR
0002          John           APRC
0024          Bob            ADMR
0011          Bob            APRC
0045          John           ADMR
```

1. Users assigned to group ADMR should only see rows where group ==
   ADMR.
2. Users assigned to group APRC should only see rows where group ==
   APRC.
3. Users assigned to both group ADMR and APRC should only see rows
   where group == ADMR or group == APRC.

There will be many groups/combinations (not just ADMR and APRC) so I would like a general solution.

I have set it up to work for users assigned to a single group as per: [How can I filter data in an Apex Grid to show certain things for certain user groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956835/how-can-i-filter-data-in-an-apex-grid-to-show-certain-things-for-certain-user-gr) . However I have been unable to work out how to make it work for multiple user groups.

This where clause works for individual groups (running from Page designer):

```
((','||apex_util.get_groups_user_belongs_to(:app_user)||',' like '%,ADMR,%'
      and group = 'ADMR')
      or 
(','||apex_util.get_groups_user_belongs_to(:app_user)||',' like '%,APRC,%'
      and group = 'APRC'))
```

But if a user is assigned to both groups only ADMR data is shown.

I thought that a non-general solution when the user is assigned to both ADMR and APRC groups could look like:

```
(
','||apex_util.get_groups_user_belongs_to(:app_user)||',' like '%,ADMR,%'
      and
','||apex_util.get_groups_user_belongs_to(:app_user)||',' like '%,APRC,%' 
      and 
 (group = 'ADMR' or group = 'APRC')
)
```

but when doing this no data is shown.

In my head, a general solution would use where in:

```
group in (','||apex_util.get_groups_user_belongs_to(:app_user)||','))
```

but when doing this no data is shown.

To work it should be the same as

```
group in ('ADMR','APRC')
```

There are no error messages.

Comment: maybe this can help http://dgielis.blogspot.com/2017/02/ or https://blogs.oracle.com/aramamoo/how-to-split-comma-separated-string-and-pass-to-in-clause-of-select-statement

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @romeuBraga for providing the framework. The following worked (I had to add the trim function).

```
  where GROUP in (
    SELECT trim(regexp_substr(','||apex_util.get_groups_user_belongs_to(:APP_USER)||',', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) 
FROM dual
    connect by regexp_substr(
('ADMR, APRC')
, '[^,]+', 1, level) 
is not null 
);
```